# Remove "»" char in string php

Tags: php, string, replace

I know my question seem duplicates but after searching many solutions in here, it didn't solved for my question.

I just want to replace or remove this char **"»"**.

I have tried:

```
$string = "Link »";
str_replace('\u00bb', '', $string); >> not work
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $string); >> not work
filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); >> not work
```

But not works!

Anybody can help me? Thanks!

Comment: And str_replace ('»', '',$string) is not working??

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $String);`

Comment: is the character always the last one, you could use trim or substring functions to achieve this

Comment: or `preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very simple to remove a character for a string use `str_replace` for PHP:

```
$str = 'some random » that exists here or » there';
echo str_replace('»', '', $str); // some random that exists here or there
```

For `str_replace` you add the character you want to replace, then what it needs to be replaced with, and finally the string you are modifying.

Comment: Oh my god, this is work.. I've been thinking too much which is made me can not think simple.

Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

- `'\u00bb'` does not equal `»`.
- C escapes foremost do not work in single quotes.
- And it would be `"\u{00bb}"` for PHP strings.
- Your charclass `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]` is just for ASCII control characters, not for this unicode codepoint.
- For the regex and this specific character you could use `\x{00bb}`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $value = str_replace('>>','',$string);
```

Comment: he's talking about the char `»`, not about twice `>`